# <identifier> error when trying to identify palindromes with stack?

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

I'm working on an assignment to identify palindromes, and I have to use a stack to do it. I'm currently getting the message error: identifier expected for:

> palStack.push(nextChar);

My professor said I'm trying to use Stack as a raw type, which is why I'm getting the error, but I'm not sure what he means exactly? I'm pretty new to data structures, so any tips on using the Stack would be appreciated!

Here's the section that I'm having an issue on:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int replay = 0; 
    Stack<char> palStack = new Stack<>(); 
    char nextChar; 
    int characterCount;
    String phrase, emptyPhrase = "", replayAns; 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while(replay != 1){
        System.out.println("Enter phrase: ");
        phrase = reader.nextLine(); 
        characterCount = phrase.length(); 

        System.out.print("Original phrase: "); 

        for(int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++){
            nextChar = phrase.charAt(i); 

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            palStack.push(nextChar);    
            System.out.print(nextChar); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
Stack<char> palStack = new Stack<>();
```

You cannot use primitives/raw types (in this case `char`) as a generic type (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). So you just need to use a reference type, which is `java.lang.Character`:

```
Stack<Character> palStack = new Stack<>();
```